# C++: How to convert C-library file IO to C++ stream IO?

Tags: c++, c

I have function like this one mentioned below, in this function filename is sent as parameter which is then opened and contents of it are read and utilized. What I want to achieve is the same functionality but by passing string(file content) to that function directly. So I want to know exactly how I should approach this and convert methods like `fgets`, `feof`

```
unsigned CalcChecksum(char *filename, unsigned &found_checksum)
{
    unsigned s, c, fcs;
    char *ch;
    char input[256];
    FILE *fp;

    s = 0;
    fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!fp)
    {
        found_checksum = 1;
        return 0;
    }
    ch = fgets(input, 255, fp);
    if ((feof(fp)) || (strncmp(input, "checksum", 8) == 0))
    {
        fclose(fp);
        return s;
    }
    while (1)
    {
        while (*ch != '\n')
        {
            c = (unsigned)*ch++;
            s = CRCtab[(s^c) & 0xFF] ^ s >> 8;
        }
        ch = fgets(input, 255, fp);
        if ((feof(fp)) || (strncmp(input, "checksum", 8) == 0))
            break;
    }
    if (strncmp(input, "checksum", 8) == 0)
    {
        fcs = 0;
        sscanf(input, "checksum 0x%x", &fcs);
        if (fcs == 0)
            sscanf(input, "checksum 0X%X", &fcs);
        found_checksum = fcs;
    }
    else
        found_checksum = 0;
    fclose(fp);
    return s;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a plain C code. Anyway, you should learn something about [C-strings](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-strings).

Comment: "like this one mentioned below" ? Is that the function or isn't it? And what *exactly* is the question? As posted, this seems more of a goal than a question concerning an actual problem. Are you asking how to convert C-library file IO to C++ stream IO ? That's a multi-step process, the first of which is understanding the C++ IO streams library and what they can/cannot do.

Comment: 'how to convert C-library file IO to C++ stream IO ?' yes this seems to be the perfect way to ask it. I dont want the whole function to be converted but get an idea how to convert Clib IO to C++ stream IO.

Comment: @n.m. I think that is precisely the not-very-clear-point. He has C, wants C++ IO streams, and wants us to tell him how to do it.

Comment: @n.m.  Looks like C to me too.  Specifically, legacy C.  Switching legacy C code to iostreams "because it's the cool thing to do" is a really bad idea.  OTOH, writing a single function which takes an istream, and then passing in an ifstream or a stringstream would be entirely sensible.

Comment: OP:  Do you want to keep the code to read from file, or do you want to end up *only* using the string version?

Comment: No read from file required, contents of file is available as std::string. Need to port the function so it parses the string. Not sure about the approach 1) should i pas string directly to the funtion or create sstream and pass it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either with Char * or std::string as your input.

```
unsigned CalcChecksum(char *fileContent, unsigned &found_checksum){
    int contentLength = strlen(filecContent);
    while(contentLength > 0){
        ...
        strncpy(input, fileContent, 255);
        fileContent+=255;
        contentLength-=255;
        ...
    }
}
```

or With std::string

```
unsigned CalcChecksum(string fileContent, unsigned &found_checksum){
    int contentLength =filecContent.length();
    int pos = 0;
    while(contentLength > 0){
        ...
        input = fileContent.substr(pos, 255);
        pos+=255;
        contentLength-=255;
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit off-topic, but one frequent error when implementing a checksum function is incorrect conversion from (signed) `char` to `unsigned`, like the one in your code:

```
c = (unsigned)*ch++;
```

Example:

```
#include <cstdio>

unsigned checksum1(char const* data, size_t data_len) {
    unsigned s = 0;
    for(char const* end = data + data_len; data != end; ++data)
        s += *data; // <--- incorrect conversion, same as s += (unsigned)*data.
    return s;
}

unsigned checksum2(char const* data, size_t data_len) {
    unsigned s = 0;
    for(char const* end = data + data_len; data != end; ++data)
        s += static_cast<unsigned char>(*data); // <--- correct conversion
    return s;
}

int main() {
    char const s[] = "© example.com";
    std::printf("%u %u\n", checksum1(s, sizeof s - 1), checksum2(s, sizeof s - 1));
}
```

Outputs:

```
996 1508
```

This is because (implicit) integer conversions first adjust the width and then change signedness. E.g., `char('©')` becomes `int(-62)` and then `unsigned(4294967234`). The signedness must be changed first: `char('©')` becomes `unsigned char(168)` and then `unsigned(168)`.

Answer (score 0):

CalcChecksum method now accepts stringstream as param.

```
unsigned CalcChecksumFromString(std::stringstream& stream, unsigned &found_checksum)
{
    unsigned s, c, fcs;
    char *ch;
    s = 0;

    if (!stream.rdbuf()->in_avail() == 0)
    {
        found_checksum = 1;
        return 0;
    }

    std::string input;
    std::getline(stream, input);
    if ((stream.eof()) || (strncmp(input.c_str(), "checksum", 8) == 0))
    {
        return s;
    }

    do
        {

        for (char& c : input) 
        {
            c = static_cast<unsigned char>(c);
            s = CRCtab[(s^c) & 0xFF] ^ s >> 8;
        }

        if ((stream.eof()) || (strncmp(input.c_str(), "checksum", 8) == 0))
            break;
    } while (std::getline(stream, input));

    if (strncmp(input.c_str(), "checksum", 8) == 0)
    {
        fcs = 0;
        sscanf(input.c_str(), "checksum 0x%x", &fcs);
        if (fcs == 0)
            sscanf(input.c_str(), "checksum 0X%X", &fcs);
        found_checksum = fcs;
    }
    else
        found_checksum = 0;
    return s;
}
```